# ObjectDataSource SelectParameter is an Object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

im using C# under Visual studio 2010

i have an object datasource that does performs a certain function taking 2 parameters the first is int, the 2nd in a list

how can i pass this list of ints to the object datasource!????

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
a=Some Function that populates the list of int by int values;
ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameter["Sources"].DefaultValue=a;
```

??
?
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public WebForm1()
        {
            this.Init += (o, e) =>
                {
                    myDS.Selecting += (ds, dsArgs) =>
                    {
                        dsArgs.InputParameters["filter"] = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
                    };
                };
        }
```

The idea is to set the parameter at the Selecting event.